# How to use DerivingVia with Arbitrary

Tags: haskell, ghc, quickcheck, deriving, derivingvia

I need to write a heck of Arbitrary instances for newtypes.
I am trying to cheap on typing and use deriving via GHC extension.

My use case complies, but blows up in runtime! GHCi is 8.8.4

```
import Test.QuickCheck (Gen, elements, listOf, Arbitrary, arbitrary)
genSafeChar = elements ['a'..'z'] 
genSafeString = listOf genSafeChar
newtype SafeString = SafeString String deriving (Show, Eq)
instance Arbitrary SafeString where arbitrary = fmap SafeString genSafeString
:set -XDerivingVia
newtype MyS = MyS String deriving (Arbitrary, Show) via SafeString
> MyS "3"
SafeString "3"
```

Show is working fine but Arbitrary doesn't!

```
> :t (arbitrary :: Gen SafeString)
(arbitrary :: Gen SafeString) :: Gen SafeString
> :t (arbitrary :: Gen MyS)

<interactive>:1:2: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘SafeString’ with ‘MyS’
      Expected type: Gen MyS
        Actual type: Gen SafeString
    • In the expression: (arbitrary :: Gen MyS)
```

Comment: That's not a runtime error. That is a type error, so it will raise at compile time. Of course in `ghci`, you write in an *interactive* manner.

Comment: What happens if you use `StandaloneDeriving` for that instance? It looks like GHC is imposing an unsatisfiable constraint on the instance, and I don't know why.

Comment: Is this the complete log? This looks like an error you would get if you shadowed `arbitrary` with a monomorphic definition.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia you are right